# How to model a many-to-many relationship between two very large tables?

Tags: sql

I have two tables `users` (whose primary key is `user_id`) and `items` (whose primary key is `item_id`).

One `user_id` (resp. `item_id`) can be associated with zero to many `item_id` (resp. `user_id`).

Under normal circumstances, I would model this many-to-many relationship with a joining table linking the two i.e. `users_items (user_id, item_id)`.

In practice however, most `user_id` are associated with all `items` rows, and with millions of `users` and `items` the matching between every single pair results in billions of rows and rapidly becomes impractical (indexation, RAM usage, storage...).

For instance, 2 million users all having 1 million items would result in 2000 billion rows.

The less-than-ideal temporary solution I came up with is to add a boolean `is_owned_by_all_users` column in the `items` table, which seems to me like an inherently bad design (more complex queries, information split between two tables etc).

Is there a better strategy to implement this type of relationship?

While this is a general SQL question, I am also interested in engine-specific implementations that would solve this problem (if more suited to this particular scenario).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've seen posed to this is that you create a "security profile" table. Each record in the table represents a particular list of users.

then instead of a many to many bridge table, you have a many to one. Each item record (many) refers to one security profile record (which actually represents many)

The security profile record represents basically a particular combination of users.

There is of course overhead in maintaining, generating, and decoding this table but it stops you needing a bridge table.

If there are a lot of different combinations, it's also impractical.

If that is not practical then your original idea sounds fine to me, if that is a particular characteristic of your data, there's nothing wrong with modelling it that way.